# How to Improve this query for performance?

Tags: mysql, performance

```
select m.ID,m.cell_number,cm.id 
from corporate_main_member m
   , corporate_main_corporate_membership cm 
WHERE m.status = 'active' 
   AND m.ID IN (
      select cm.FK_Member_ID 
      from corporate_main_corporate_membership cm 
      WHERE cm.status = 'active' 
        AND cm.ID IN (
           select gm.FK_Corporate_Membership_ID 
           from corporate_main_group_membership gm 
           WHERE gm.status = 'active' 
             AND gm.FK_Group_id IN (168,169,170)
             Group BY gm.FK_Corporate_Membership_ID
           )
      ) 
   AND cm.fk_corporation_id = 5 
   AND cm.FK_Member_ID = m.id
```

On:

```
1 Million records of corporate_main_member 
2 Million records of corporate_main_corporate_membership
3 Million records of corporate_main_group_membership
```

The above query halts mysql! It was working until day before yesterday when I added a few thousands records using a script to corporate_main_member and corporate_main_corporate_membership tables. Not sure if it is related or the db size crossed some threshold that caused drastic performance issue.

Any help? I have no idea about the indexes or anything. The schema is obvious.

Comment: Have you tried using left joins?

Comment: Can you describe what the query is supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 2):

try this one,

```
SELECT  m.ID,
        m.cell_number,
        cm.id
FROM    corporate_main_member m
        INNER JOIN corporate_main_corporate_membership cm
            ON  cm.FK_Member_ID = m.id  AND
                cm.fk_corporation_id = 5
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ccm.FK_Member_ID
            FROM    corporate_main_corporate_membership ccm
                    INNER JOIN corporate_main_group_membership gm
                        ON ccm.ID = gm.FK_Corporate_Membership_ID
            WHERE   ccm.STATUS = 'active' AND
                    gm.STATUS = 'active' AND
                    gm.FK_Group_id IN ( 168, 169, 170 )
            GROUP   BY ccm.FK_Member_ID
        ) s ON  m.ID = s.FK_Member_ID
WHERE   m.STATUS = 'active'
```